# My file download have ` PK z—LO‹Ý< _rels/.rels<?xml vers...` in front end

Tags: xml, angular, typescript, blob

I have the problem when I download the file.

I download the file with this text:

```
PK
     z—LO‹Ý<       _rels/.rels<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Target="word/document.xml" Id="pkgRId0" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" /></Relationships>PK
     z—LÜó À–  –     word/_rels/document.xml.rels<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Target="numbering.xml" Id="docRId0" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering" /><Relationship Target="styles.xml" Id="docRId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" /></Relationships>PK
     c…˜Lx»s/  /     word/document.xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:pPr><w:spacing w:before="0" w:after="200" w:line="276" /><w:ind w:right="0" w:left="0" w:firstLine="0" /><w:jc w:val="left" /><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Calibri" w:eastAsia="Calibri" /><w:color w:val="auto" /><w:spacing w:val="0" /><w:position w:val="0" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" /></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Calibri" w:eastAsia="Calibri" /><w:color w:val="auto" /><w:spacing w:val="0" /><w:position w:val="0" /><w:sz w:val="72" /><w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" /></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document>PK
     z—L,1¿q         word/numbering.xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><w:numbering xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />PK
     z—L¯SÈAŠ   Š      word/styles.xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />PK
     z—Lÿbkº]  ]     [Content_Types].xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"><Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" /><Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml" /><Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml" /><Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml" /></Types>PK
     c…˜L               word/PK 
     z—LO‹Ý<                     _rels/.relsPK 
     z—LÜó À–  –               E  word/_rels/document.xml.relsPK 
     c…˜Lx»s/  /                 word/document.xmlPK 
     z—L,1¿q                   s  word/numbering.xmlPK 
     z—L¯SÈAŠ   Š                0  word/styles.xmlPK 
     z—Lÿbkº]  ]               ç  [Content_Types].xmlPK 
     c…˜L                        u   word/PK      ³
```

In fact this is not the text that I want to download.

I tried this code:
my service code:

```
  public download(id: string): Observable<any> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    headers.append('sale_id', id);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    headers.append('responseType', 'blob');
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.download), {
      headers: headers,
     responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
    }).map(res => res.blob())
  }
```

my component code:

```
  exportExcel(id: string) {
    this.ss.download(id)
      .subscribe(data => { console.log(`excel data: ${data}`); FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'people-export.xlsx') },
        error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
        () => console.log('Completed file download.'));
  }
```

my html code:

```
  <button>
<i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"(click)="exportExcel(item.sale_id)"></i>
  </button>
```

Please, I need your support. Thank you

Comment: `PK` is the [magic of ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), and recent versions of Excel indeed do use zipfiles as their data format. What you're downloading is not plain text, so that checks out. Can the resulting file be opened in Excel? If not, the binary data may be mangled by an encoding issue somewhere as it gets transported to the server, or the server's `Content-Type` is wrong in the response.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I completely overlooked that this is about Excel, just saw the "PK" and thought: Oh yeah!

Comment: @Shnugo: don't feel bad, I almost wrote up something about using `Content-Encoding: identity` to suppress the server's compression, before I remembered that zip and gzip are not related...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PK` at the beginning tells you, that this is a zipped file. Try to open this file with 7-zip or any other unzipping tool.

The zip-format was created by `P`hil `K`atz ("zip" was formerly known as "PKWARE") :-D

Jeroen Mostert is right: Modern Excel files (`.xlsx`) are zipped files. Changing their extension to `.zip` allows to open such a file within Explorer just as any other ZIP-file.

You find the Worksheet's data within the directory `xl` as `sheet1` or `sheet2`

Comment: Oh no, really :( I don't believe it. Thank you.  When I tried to postman this wm, function normally, download me file.txt, but in this code no. Also, I tried this  `people-export.xlsx` to `people-export.zip` and now are some file, but no my file that I want. Any idea please?

Comment: @OnnaB You might export this to a comma separated format (Excel can open such CSV-files natively). Otherwise you'd have to understand the given format and create a properly formed package and store this as zipped file with the extension `.xlsx`. But this is not trivial. Before you start to develop I'd try to find something out there :-D

Comment: Please, can you ask me any example how to convert this file in pdf with real data? I tried some example, but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes I write new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016568/how-to-manage-responsetype-blob-using-angular5-in-front-end but no answer :(